# Как сделать все одним запросом mysql?

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Есть таблица, ну, можете представить, таблица магазина.
Я использую `select sql_calc_found_rows * ...`.
Потом запросом `select found_rows() ...`.  
То есть я не делаю такого же второго запроса, чтоб узнать количество записей, а использую встроенный подсчет.

Можно ли как-то также в конце найти максимальную и минимальную цену полученных записей?
Это нужно для фильтровки в магазине, чтобы показало, мол, вот товары нашлись, цены от 100 до 9890 р.
Человек берет и ставит, мол, показывай только до 5000 р...

Надеюсь, вопрос понятен?
Ну или предложите свои варианты реализации.
Для упрощения таблица имеет структуру:
Ид / имятовара / цена

Comment: @armenka, обычно такие вещи просто кэшируют, на уровне БД (создаются дополнительные поля у записи раздела или связанная таблица метаданных разделов) или приложения (кэш в оперативке или файлах).

Comment: Почитайте про "rollup" и "cube".